# How to access to object variables dynamically in python

Tags: python-3.x, oop, instance

I have tried to access to object variables dynamically.
The question is how to access with variables to object properties.
For example:

```
    >>> my_obj = x_class()
    >>> property = "name"
    >>> my_obj.property = "Rick"
    >>> my_obj.name
    "Rick"
```

I have found some answers but in JS not in python
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/04/12/getattr-setattr.html) gives a detailed explanation to what you're looking for.

Comment: i have tried with `setattr()` but i does not change the variable, when i ask for it, retrieves the past value

Comment: My bad i was trying with `setattr(obj, "property", value)` instead of `setattr(obj, property, value)`, thanks to all